# gmap-autocomplete not displaying map with Twitter-bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the gmaps-autocomplete ( rjshade  @ https://github.com/rjshade/gmaps-autocomplete/blob/master/js/gmaps.js) in my Rails app.
The text-field autocomplete is running fine , starting keyin an address produce the dropdown selection from which the user can select the address

however upon complete, the google map should be displayed in the corresponding div #gmaps-canvas... and the latitude/longitude data should be displayed too in the corresponding div #gmaps-output-latitude , #gmaps-output-longitude...

but nothing is actually displayed ..

I am using Twitter-bootstrap , is there any problem using both ?  how can I check any error  ( no javascript error in the console )

Answer (score 1):

the gem is working fine , I forgot to set height/width for the #gmap-canvas div

```
#gmaps-canvas{:style => "width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 200px; border: solid 1px;"}
```